# Very slow startup after update to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, boot-time

My hardware:

```
Dell Latitude D600 laptop
Processor: Intel Pentium (r) 1.8 GHz
Memory 1.2 GiB
Graphics R200 (RV250 4C66) x86/MMX/SSE2 TCL DRI2
Disk: 37.7 gb
```

I did an update from 11.?? using the automatic system update that pops up when you switch/log on.

Ever since then when I switch on the machine it takes approximately one hour to get to the login screen.

Sometimes the actual login will take time too, but sometimes within a couple of minutes I am logged in.

Once I am logged in I find I can work normally, the response is not swift, but is neither too slow that I cannot work.

I was wondering if there was anything I could do to speed things up.

I deliberately did not do a clean install from disk, because I did not want to loose settings on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing some, 'spring cleaning' removing old kernels? If not open up terminal (ctrl+alt+T) and paste the following commands:

Taking note of the most recent kernel

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

This will reveal all kernels presently installed on your system. Look for outdated kernels.

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic
```

Where x.x.x.x is the kernels you're wanting to remove, that is, outdated kernels.

```
sudo update-grub2
```

To update grub2.

Comment: and@ubuntu10-laptop1:~$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-31-generic 3.2.0-31.50  Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-32-generic 3.2.0-32.51 Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic 3.2.0.32.35   Generic Linux kernel image

I found many and removed as recommended, they were all of version 2....
However, left these three as I am not sure if removing .35 and .50 would help.
The problems persists,
but I do not know enough to be confident about removing the remaining.

Answer (score -1):

For one command, try this (copy and past on bash):

```
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work. Your sed is invalid. Please also post explanations of what this does before you blindly feed packages to apt-get purge.